# Virustotal api: как загрузить файл?

Tags: python, api

Как загрузить файл на Virustotal, используя api?

Comment: используя api..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan'
params = {'apikey': '<apikey>'}
files = {'file': ('myfile.exe', open('myfile.exe', 'rb'))}
response = requests.post(url, files=files, params=params)
print(response.json())
```

Взят из [документации](https://developers.virustotal.com/reference#file-scan)

Comment: open('myfile.exe', 'rb') не обязательно использовать